# 1990s cartoon movie - Bugs Bunny anti-drugs

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I recall that the film had Bugs Bunny and his crew and they talk about drugs and how they're bad for you.

It's been bothering me for years about this movie.

Comment: For those voting "off topic, not scifi/fantasy" you may want to note that this property contains aliens, ninja turtles and ghosts.

Comment: @Valorum - But the film might not have, yes? It might just have been anthropomorphic animals talking about drugs.

Comment: @Adamant - In this case, having identified that it is indeed on-topic, it seems a bit churlish to vote to close it as off-topic.

Comment: @Valorum - I didn’t see that there was an answer in the First Posts queue. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bugs Bunny anti-drugs PSA is probably [Cartoon All Stars to the Rescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartoon_All-Stars_to_the_Rescue).

Along with Bugs, it also starred a host of other animated characters; ALF, Alvin and the Chipmunks, Huey, Dewey, and Louie, Garfield, Daffy Duck, Porky Pig, Baby Kermit, Baby Piggy, Baby Gonzo, Winnie the Pooh, Tigger, Slimer, The Smurfs &  Michelangelo the turtle.

Comment: Thank you so much that it. Now I just got to find the other 1

Comment: @Cassaundra - Post it as a new question